# GCM : java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to register a device onto GCM using the following code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    // the following function can be removed when deploying the app
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
      Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
```

I have imported import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

and also added GCM.jar to my buildpath in Eclipse which i got thru the sdk download

Please help !

Comment: You should put the jar in your libs folder (not lib), and verify it is in the "Android dependencies" list. Sometimes I found out re-arranging the order of the dependencies changes behavior, so you can try it also

Comment: thanks i copied the jar file to the libs folder and it seems to work !

Comment: @Shushu: the jar is in my libs folder, but not in dependencies. So, how to add it in dependencies?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the updated ADT(Above ADT 17) you have to put jar files inside `libs` folder and not `lib`. So make sure that you put `gcm.jar` file inside `libs` and not `lib` folder.

Comment: my gcm.jar is inside libs and i hae configures path still no success

Answer (score 28):

Just go to project properties -> java build path -> "order and export " now giv a tick on the jar file "GCM.jar" that you have added

Answer (score 10):

My `gcm.jar` was already in libs, so it wasn't a folder naming issue for me..

I had to go to `Right Click` > `Build Path` > `Configure Build path...` for the project in question and I removed the following:

- Any lingering files outside of a folder/bundle
- `Android Private Libraries`
- Any bundles with the word 'reference' in them (you may not have one)

You might get a lot of "errors" in your project so restart Eclipse and let it clean. Once it cleans you'll have no errors. Run your project and viola.

Thanks to **DLew** for this answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! this answer may have had zero votes and been pretty far down the page but it's the one that worked when all the others failed for me!

Comment: Your answer is great and its worked for me. Thanks to Jackson and BLT also

Answer (score 6):

Make a folder **libs** in your project folder and put the gcm.jar in it. Then add it to your class path using **add external jars** in **configure build path** option.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put gcm.jar file inside *libs*, then go to project *Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries* and add it to your path using *Add External JARs...*, after in *Order and Export* you check gcm.jar and press *OK*. That should work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the gcm jar file is in the right libs folder and added into the java build path at your project properties.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, after update SDK in my project. 
it helped for me: I just "add support library" in "Android tools". Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Me also got same problem, after adding `android-support-v4.jar` and `gcm.jar` into my libs folder no issues found its work like a charm

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SENDER_ID field should be the project ID from when you created your google api project.
Read the beginning of this: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#libs

TAG should also be a string ->  ""tag Name"

Answer (score 0):

Hello You are using old GCM implementations use new implementations available on
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start